# Sort table by matching record percentage

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with `parent_id` and `percentage_score` which is a result of a simple deduplication. My problem now is how can I select the records and arrange them like this:

```
|id|lastname|firstname|number|parent_id|percentage_score|
--------------------------------------------------------
|1 |holmes  | james   |11112 |  0      |100%            |
|7 |holmes  | john    |11112 |  1      |80%             |
|8 |holmes  | james   |11113 |  1      |60%             |
|4 |sherlock| steve   |77777 |  0      |100%            |
|9 |sherlock| stove   |77777 |  4      |80%             |
|12|ketchum | ash     |00001 |  0      |100%            |
```

I tried using order by `parent_id, percentage_score` but that's not even near to what I want.

Comment: Why don't you GROUP BY last name and then sort by percent_score?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is confusing because your expected result does not seem to be in a logical order. But, you can use the `DESC` command to change the priority in the ORDER by clause, like this:

```
SELECT id, lastname, firstname, number, parent_id, percentage_score
ORDER BY parent_id, percentage_score DESC
```

Comment: I wan't it to sort by the matching records. parent first, then it's child ordered by the percentage.

Comment: How do you tell which record is a matching record? If it shows up in the query record set? The results you have do not list the parent_id in either an ascending or descending order.